# Existence of an isometry in an arbitrary space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products

I am trying to prove the following and want to see if I am on the right track.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space with dimension $n$ over either the field $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$. Then there exists an isometry $T : V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^n$, where $\mathbb{F}^n$ is equipped with the standard inner product.

My idea is the following. Let $v_1, \dotsc, v_n$ be an orthonormal basis of $V$. Write some $v \in V$ as $v = a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_nv_n$. Then $\Vert v \Vert^2 = \langle v, v \rangle = \lvert a_1 \rvert^2 + \cdots + \lvert a_n\rvert^2$.

It seems the desired isometry $T$ should be defined by $v \mapsto \lvert a_1 \rvert e_1 + \cdots + \lvert a_n \rvert e_n$, where $e_j$ is the $j$th standard basis vector in $\mathbb{F}^n.$ Then we would indeed have $\langle Tv, Tv \rangle = \langle v, v\rangle.$ But I do not think this works, since $T$ is not injective.

How can I fix this argument? Or is there a better, different way to approach this problem?

Comment: Why is $T$ not injective?

Comment: Because $Tv = T(-v)$.

Comment: Oh, I missed those absolute value bars. Have you considered the mapping you get without them?

Comment: Okay, so mapping $v_i \mapsto e_i$ gives $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle = \langle Tv_i, Tv_j\rangle$ since the $v_i$'s and $e_i$'s are orthonormal. Does linearity take care of the rest?

Comment: It will! But since you seem to not be entirely sure, write it down explicitly and convince yourself that it does.

Comment: I will, thank you!